# Arithmetic in dockerfile w/ environment variables

Tags: dockerfile

I've a docker file which exposes a port based on env variable `$PORT_NUMBER` like below:

```
EXPOSE $PORT_NUMBER
```

I'm trying to expose another port by adding 1 to `$PORT_NUMBER` - something like:

```
EXPOSE $PORT_NUMBER + 1
```

How do I do that?